# BottomSheetFragment и BottomNaigationView

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-navigation-view, android-bottomsheetbehavior

Каким образом можно BottomSheetFragment поднять над BottomNavigationView (что-то похожее на дизайн яндекс.навигатор), то есть, чтобы BottomSheetFragment не закрывал BottomNavigationView?

Answer (score 0):

Может я плохо понимаю всю задачу. Но более простым решением такой задачи будет сделать так чтоб Bottom Sheet всегда торчал снизу и вот на этой торчащей части сделать ваш navigation view.

А то что пытаетесь сделать вы, как мне кажется какой-то дикий костыль.